# OData filter objects that contain particular items in subarray

Tags: odata

I have the following situation:

1. I have an object
2. This object has an item that is an object again
3. The second object contains array of objects with ids

Can I filter only the parent objects that have subobjects that contain something in particular in the array on the bottom of the tree?

Comment: It helps these types of questions if you include an example _hypothetical_ model, then we can all use the specific fields and avigation paths from your example rather than guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filter=nameOfObjectArrayProperty/any(o: contains(o/id, 'some-alue'))
```

or

```
$filter=nameOfObjectArrayProperty/any(o: o/id eq 'some-value')
```

It's also important to note that "/any" can be replaced with "/all" if you want all the subobjects to match your filter criteria.